# Undefined reference to static const class member while using std::min on GCC 4.8.4

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

When I try to compile following code (using *g++ 4.8.4* with *-std=c++11*) :

```
#include <algorithm>

class A
{
    public:
        static const unsigned a = 1;
        //static const unsigned a;
};

// const unsigned A::a = 1;

int main()
{
    unsigned b = 2;
    std::min(/*(unsigned)*/A::a, b);
}
```

I've got linking error:

> undefined reference to `A::a`

If I define `A::a` outside of **class A** or cast `A::a` to unsigned while executing `std::min` problem does not exist.

Is it GCC bug? If not what's the root cause of such behavior?

Comment: binding to a reference = ODR use